# heroku certs:info --app appname does not write to STDOUT or STDERR

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I'm trying to process the output of the `heroku certs` command. Other commands in the heroku toolbelt write to STDOUT, but `heroku certs` and related commands like `heroku certs:info` do not appear to be written anywhere I would expect on ubuntu. Output when run normally:

```
$ heroku certs:info --app appname
Fetching SSL Endpoint changedname-3302.herokussl.com info for appname... done
Certificate details:
Common Name(s): *.domain.com
                domain.com

...etc
```

Output with attempts to redirect or pipe output:

```
$ heroku certs --app appname | grep ssl
$ heroku certs --app appname | cat
$ heroku certs:info --app appname | grep ssl
$ heroku certs:info --app appname 2>&1 | grep ssl
$ heroku certs:info --app appname &> /tmp/certs.info; cat /tmp/certs.info
$ heroku certs:info --app appname > /tmp/certs.info; cat /tmp/certs.info
```

Other heroku commands work as expected:

```
$ heroku ps --app appname | grep web
=== web (1X): `node www`
web.1: idle 2013/10/12 05:44:15 (~ 10h ago)

$ heroku status --app appname | grep -i status
=== Heroku Status
```

Is this a bug that should be reported or something I'm missing?

Comment: I believe I've found the answer. The script opens /dev/tty directly and bypasses STDERR/STDOUT/STDIN. Found the answer here:

http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/152781-bash-capturing-anything-showed-screen.html

I can see how some of the cert information shouldn't be captured.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am similarly trying to capture the output of `heroku certs` so that we can automate our DNS setup.

As you've also found, the Heroku toolbelt script won't redirect output for any of the `certs` commands. Digging into the ruby implementation, it's in this overriding of the 'display' method:

```
def display(msg = "", new_line = true)
  super if $stdout.tty?
end
```

(https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/master/lib/heroku/command/certs.rb#L188)

If it doesn't think its outputting to a /dev/tty, it won't print anything at all.

As a quick hack, I instead used a `curl` equivalent as a drop-in replacement:

```
curl -n -s -X GET https://api.heroku.com/apps/my_app_name/ssl-endpoints -H "Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3"
```

The `-n` option will get curl to use the ~/.netrc entry that the `heroku` script already uses.  The output is in JSON, along these lines.

```
[
  {
    "cname":"xxxx-xxxx.herokussl.com",
    "id":"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "name":"xxxx-xxxx",
    "warnings":[],
    "ssl_cert":{
      "ca_signed?":true,
      "cert_domains":[
        "*.xxxxxxxx.com",
        "xxxxxxxx.com"
      ],
      "expires_at":"xxxx",
      "issuer":"xxxx",
      "self_signed?":false,
      "starts_at":"xxxx",
      "subject":"xxxx"
    },
    "ssl_cert_prev":null
  }
]
```

Depending on how you are wrapping the scripts, this may be even more parseable than the `heroku` output.